# Como usar correctamente "as" para varios campos de una tabla en php y MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo un query con el que obtengo varios campos de una tabla, posteriormente con While hago un ciclo para recorrer los resultados, y cada uno me arroja la clave y el valor de cada campo.

Ej:

primer resultado -> 
fecha1: 2019-10-10
fecha2: 2019-10-11

segundo resultado ->
fecha1: 2019-08-02
fecha2: 2019-08-03

tercer resultado ->
fecha1: 2019-03-05
fecha2: 2019-03-06

Lo que quiero lograr es que las palabras claves dejen de ser "fecha1" o "fecha2" y se conviertan en la palabra "fechas", sin necesidad de cambiar el nombre de los campos en mi base de datos.

acá esta mi código

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion2, "SELECT fecha1, fecha2, fecha3, fecha4,fecha5,fecha6,fecha7,fecha8,fecha9,fecha10,fecha11,fecha12,fecha13,fecha14,fecha15,fecha16,fecha17,fecha18,fecha19,fecha20,fecha21,fecha22,fecha23,fecha24,fecha25,fecha26,fecha27,fecha28,fecha29,fecha30,fecha31 AS fechas  FROM nairoquinatanalopez63");

$datos = array();
while ($resultados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)){

$datos[] = $resultados;

}


//print_r($datos); 

$final = json_encode($datos);

echo $final;
```

Como ven , ya probé usando - SELECT fecha1, fecha2... AS fechas  FROM nairoquinatanalopez63 -
en mi query pero el resultado solo se aplica a la ultima palabra clave - fecha31-.

De antemano gracias por su ayuda

Comment: MAs alla que tenes una respuesta correcta, me interesaria saber como es que tenes una tabla que tiene 31 campos fecha... es realmente.. muy raro...

Comment: @gbianchi es cierto, y que pasa con el mes de febrero? ┐(´•_•`)┌

Comment: desconozco la utilidad de poner en una tabla 31 campos fecha.. no se me cae una idea de porque hacer algo asi @erika_chan.. estoy abierto a ideas nuevas...

Comment: Más allá de aprender cómo utilizar alias, deberías plantearte la estructura de tu tabla, hará tediosas, complicadas y poco eficientes las consultas de esa tabla, con campo fecha, el id de la relación si la hay y N filas sería todo más facil. Te recomiendo leer sobre normalizacion, intentando empezar por 1FN https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primera_forma_normal

Comment: Yo también me pregunto si no hay un grave error de diseño en las tablas de tu base de datos. ¿Por qué tantas columnas de fecha?

Answer (score 1):

La sintaxis de `<field> AS <alias>` para el campo siempre aplicará a 1 solo campo. Por eso solo lo aplica para el último o los campos que vayan con `AS`, ya que no se puede aplicar un solo alias para multiples campos de una tabla. Lo que podrias hacer es concaternar las fechas y asi poder asignarle el alias.

tomando el ejemplo, quedaria algo asi:

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion2, "SELECT CONCAT(fecha1, ', ', fecha2....) AS fechas FROM nairoquinatanalopez63");

$datos = array();
while ($resultados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)){

$datos = explode(" ", $resultados );

}
```

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres que todos los campos de fechas se muestren en una sola columna llamada "fechas" lo que puedes hacer es concatenarlas todas, para eso puedes usar "CONCAT_WS()" así:

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion2, "SELECT concat_ws(',',fecha1, fecha2, fecha3, fecha4,fecha5,fecha6,fecha7,fecha8,fecha9,fecha10,fecha11,fecha12,fecha13,fecha14,fecha15,fecha16,fecha17,fecha18,fecha19,fecha20,fecha21,fecha22,fecha23,fecha24,fecha25,fecha26,fecha27,fecha28,fecha29,fecha30,fecha31) AS fechas  FROM nairoquinatanalopez63");

$datos = array();
while ($resultados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)){

$datos[] = $resultados;

}
```

Con "CONCAT_WS" el primer parametro es el caracter o cadena que se concatenará entre el resto de parametros que pongas en la función, por ejemplo si pones:

```
select concat_ws(',',fecha1, fecha2, fecha3) as fechas
```

Esto te dará

```
fechas
2001-01-01,2002-02-02,2003-03-03
```